# Linq query GroupBy value and determine if value meets multiple criteria

Tags: linq

Scandata has two fields, hostname and pluginID. There are numerous pluginids listed for each hostname.
In this query, I'm trying to return scanstatus as true for a host when both pluginids are assigned to that host. If only one or none is found, return false. I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what. This returns false whether one or both pluginids are listed for a given host.

```
        var goodscan = scandata.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(g => g.hostname)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                hostname = s.Key,
                scanstatus = s.All(v => v.pluginid.Contains("19506") && v.pluginid.Contains("117887"))
            })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Enumerable.All` query checks if **ALL** scans in each host-group have a `pluginid` which contains "19506" **AND** "117887"at the same time. Thats incorrect.

You want to know for each hostname-group if there is at least **ONE** scan with `pluginid` "19506" and **ANOTHER** with "117887", so use `Any` instead of `All`:

```
var goodscan = scandata.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(g => g.hostname)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        hostname = s.Key,
        scanstatus = s.Any(v => v.pluginid.Contains("19506")) 
                  && s.Any(v => v.pluginid.Contains("117887"))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I see it, makes total sense. I'll blame coding late on a Friday!